# trap is not catching HUP / SIGHUP

Tags: bash, shell-script, trap

I have these bash function:

```
on_ql_trap(){
  echo "foobar" > "$HOME/.quicklock/debug.json"
}

ql_trap(){
  trap on_ql_trap EXIT;
  trap on_ql_trap 0;
  trap on_ql_trap SIGHUP;
  trap on_ql_trap HUP;
}
```

ql_trap is called by the user, but when the user closes the bash shell window that called the function, on_ql_trap never gets called, witness by the fact that 'foobar' is never written out.

the only thing I can think of, is that `trap` is not being registered for the right process or something. Does anyone know how I can guarantee that `on_ql_trap` will be called when process ends?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but if I put them all on the same line, seems to work:

```
  trap on_ql_trap EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM;
```